# How to display agreement text in a TextArea?

Tags: jsp, textarea

I'm new to JSP programming and I'm wondering how can I display license agreement text in a text area? When I read it as a String and display it - the formatting of new lines and numbering of points is all lost. Or is there any other way of showing this text?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add you licence text with javascript including HTML bullet points etc.

```
<script>
    function addContent() {
        document.getElementById("YourTextAreaId").innerHTML= "<p>Some HTML stuff</p>";
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I think he's trying to display it for the end-user, not for editing purposes. In your answer HTML tags would be displayed, and the end-user will be very confused.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a good option, would be to use a div instead of a text area, which will be formatted with HTML, that could be entered in a WYSIWYG text area, like the one in stackoverflow.

You could use the CSS

```
div.license-agreement
{
    width: 600px; // SET AS YOU WISH
    height: 200px; // SET AS YOU WISH
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

To get the scrolling bars in the DIV.